# Using Surefire plugin in maven testcases are not running in Command line. Same testcases are running through Eclipse IDE

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

On trying to run the testcase through command line using maven framework, there are no error but 0 testcases are running. I have Junit 4 plugin with surefire plugin of 2.19.1

```
<plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.19.1</version>
        <configuration>
         <includes>
            <include>CheckoutPageStepDefinationTest.java</include>
          </includes>
         <parallel>methods</parallel>
         <useUnlimitedThreads>true</useUnlimitedThreads>
        </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

```
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
    <dependency>
     <groupId>junit</groupId>
     <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
     <version>4.13.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aZKXG.png)

Testcases should run from command line using surefire plugin

Comment: How do you run it? Maybe you need to explicitely do mvn test?

Comment: Please add the test code to the post ...